# Yocto image : getconf not found

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto

I built a yocto image (for rpi) but I can't use getconf command. it said command not found.

How can I add getconf to my image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried answering you on IRC but you disappeared to quickly.

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path /usr/bin/getconf
glibc-utils: /usr/bin/getconf
```

Install glibc-utils.